# Extract Data from Salesforce from command line

Tags: data-export, commandline

I want to extract data from Salesforce from command line. I can use data loader by creating process-config file but I need to automate this process using windows batch file. For example, I have 5 different objects in SF from where I need to pull data regularly. The data pull from those 5 objects will always be from a several orgs (not a single org). Is there a way to extract data from salesforce for those 5 objects without having to create a map file. The reason for not creating map file is that the 5 objects may differ from org to org. Hard coding the SOQL will not work for my requirement. Any suggestions as to how I can achieve this in Salesforce?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar project for a client.
I used DataLoader + Batch script file to automate extract / import data from/to Salesforce.

Look a this amazing tutorial to Setting up Automated DataLoader.

http://www.developerforce.com/media/Cheatsheet_Setting_Up_Automated_Data_Loader_9_0.pdf

At the end you'll be able to launch a script (.bat file).
Then you can create a Scheduled Task on your server to automate all your processes.

I remember that i had to hard code my SOQL query in the process-conf.xml and my map files. I used Node.js to run some script to read/write DataLoader process-conf.xml file and to create some map file etc... (Another exemple : Creating log files...)

For your MAP FILES :

- **EXTRACT** : It's not mandatory to use a map file (Your .csv header will be filed by your fields API's names)
- **IMPORT** : If you specify field API NAME in the header of your .csv file, Salesforce will automatically map your fields with SalesForce.

I hope it will help you !

Comment: I only need to extract data from Salesforce, so not creating a map file is a great news. So as per the cheatsheet there will be a SOQL query in the process-conf.xml. For instance, I need to extract data from the Users (all fields) object in Salesforce. How can I extract data from a User object without writing a SOQL query with all the field names? Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: As your know, you can't do a SELECT * FROM User... I think that the best way is to create a big SOQL with all your fields... Your fields will not change everyday.
Or, if you can retrieve all the fields with SalesForce API you can create a script that create a SOQL query with all requested fields...
As i said, i did it for a client. I created a Node.js script (but you can do it with other script languages) to create a SOQL query dynamically. I think this is the best way... :/

Comment: @FabienHuot- I am able to generate a csv using the cheat sheet and still not able to find a way to retrieve all fields for an object. Have the SOQL query in the process-conf.xml file. I haven't worked on node.js. Can you give some guidance around how to retrieve all fields via Node.js or any scripting language. Thanks.

Comment: @LearningMacro I don't remember but you can use SalesForce API to retrieve a JSON file with all fields. (I used NodeJS but you can use other script languages) :)
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_describe.htm

You can parse the JSON to retrieve all your Objects fields and then build a dynamic SOQL query

I hope it will help you

Comment: @LearningMacro any news ? :)

Comment: Still struggling to get field names dynamically. Do not have a lot of exposure to scripting language and integration of scripting language with process-conf bean. Any help is greatly appreciated.